# Errors , while parsing stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting the following *error in italic* while creating the **stored procedure in sql server(in bold),**

*Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure IATF_upload_exce, Line 46
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure IATF_upload_exce, Line 64
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure IATF_upload_exce, Line 65
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure IATF_upload_exce, Line 102
Incorrect syntax near ','*

**STORED PROCEDURE**

```
**-- ================================================
-- Template generated from Template Explorer using:
-- Create Procedure (New Menu).SQL
--
-- Use the Specify Values for Template Parameters 
-- command (Ctrl-Shift-M) to fill in the parameter 
-- values below.
--
-- This block of comments will not be included in
-- the definition of the procedure.
-- ================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Shivam_nxf30130
-- Create date: 11April2018
-- Description: IATF_upload_excel
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE IATF_upload_exce 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    --@p1 int = 0, 
    --@p2 int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name 
--DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files 
--DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup 
--DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name 
--SET @path = 'C:\Backup\' 
--SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) 
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
(SELECT 
                            AU.id                       AS audit_id,
                            AT.id                       AS audittype_id,
                            CC.id                       AS CausingClause_id,
                            IA.[Finding]                AS findings,
                            IA.[Rating]                 AS Rating,
                            IA.[Reach(L/R/G)]           AS lr_ind,
                            IA.[Root_Cause]             AS root_cause,
                            IA.[Corrective_Action]      AS corr_action,
                            IA.[Action_Owner]           AS by_whom,
                            IA.[Remark_Verification]    AS remarks,
                            IA.[Links]                  AS links,
                            IA.[Close Date]             AS close_date
                    FROM    [dbo].[IMPORT_AUDIT_REPORTS_EXCEL] AS IA,
                            [dbo].[Causing_Clause] AS CC,
                            [dbo].[Audit_Type] AS AT,                       
                            [dbo].[Audits] AS AU
                    WHERE   IA.ID           = CC.name
                    AND     IA.Audit_Type   = AT.name
                    AND     IA.Audit_No     = AU.id) AS Src
            --ON        Src.ID                  = dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .id
            --AND       Src.audittype_id        = dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .audittype_id
            --AND       Src.CausingClause_id    = dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .CausingClause_id
OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
      ---SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK' 
      --BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName 
      --FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name 
      if(Src.ID                 = dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .id
            AND     Src.audittype_id        = dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .audittype_id
            AND     Src.CausingClause_id    = dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .CausingClause_id)

            UPDATE SET  dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[audit_id]           = Src.audit_id,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[category_id]        = (SELECT id FROM [dbo].CATEGORIES AS CA WHERE CA.name = Src.Rating),
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[ref_id]         = 0,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[ref_ident]          = 'N/A',
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[findings]           = Src.findings,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[corr_action]        = Src.corr_action,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[lr_ind]         = Src.lr_ind,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[by_whom]            = Src.by_whom,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[remarks]            = Src.remarks,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[due_date]           = NULL,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[close_date]     = Src.close_date,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[audittype_id]       = Src.audittype_id,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[root_cause]     = Src.root_cause,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[links]              = Src.links,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[CausingClause_id]   = Src.CausingClause_id
    Else
INSERT
    (
        [audit_id],
        [category_id],
        [ref_id],
        [ref_ident],
        [findings],
        [corr_action],
        [lr_ind],
        [by_whom],
        [remarks],
        [due_date],
        [close_date],
        [audittype_id],
        [root_cause],
        [links],
        [CausingClause_id]
    )
    VALUES
    (
        Src.audit_id,
        (SELECT id FROM [dbo].CATEGORIES AS CA WHERE CA.name = Src.Rating),
        0,
        'N/A',
        Src.findings,
        Src.corr_action,
        Src.lr_ind,
        Src.by_whom,
        Src.remarks,
        NULL,
        Src.close_date,
        Src.audittype_id,
        Src.root_cause,
        Src.links,
        Src.CausingClause_id
    );  

END 
CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor 
END
GO**
```

Please help me in solving the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should investigate error message carefully      **AND     IA.Audit_No     = AU.id) AS Src** and **UPDATE SET** are the parts of the query that are throwing the errors.

Comment: I believe you cannot have an ALIAS when declaring a variable this way (only if it is a datatype) and you need to specify table name you wish to update.

Comment: This is not how a cursor works, please re-read the documentation. The `Src` alias within your `WHILE` loop has no meaning.

Comment: This looks like you took something from a merge statement and C/P into a cursor. Your not even fetching a new row at the end of the Cursor. Are you sure you need a cursor for this?

Comment: Hi MadBert, Thanks for the response.

Comment: @plaidDK,yes correct i have taken it from Merge and i am doing it using cursor as the sql version that i am using doesnot support MERGE. So, any other way of doing this.

Comment: Why would you take something from a set based process and make it slower and more complicated? Using a cursor here is absolutely the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @MadBert Hi MadBert, Thanks for the response. I had made the following changes , INSERT into dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS(included the table name) and UPDATE dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS(included the table name)

Comment: @MadBert but got following error, Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure IATF_upload_exce, Line 46
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Procedure IATF_upload_exce, Line 101
The name "Src.audit_id" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure IATF_upload_exce, Line 102
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Any alternative way of doing this.

Comment: If your sql server version doesn't support MERGE, you are not using sql server 2008 R2, please fix your tags.

Comment: There are so many syntax and logical errors here it would simpler to start from scratch. Your Update syntax is incorrect, the insert is incorrect, the if statement is not even close to working, your cursor syntax and logic make absolutely no sense at all. You stated that the version of sql server does not support MERGE. Are you sure? It became available in sql 2005.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the syntax for [UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql).  You need something like:

```
UPDATE table
SET col1 = ..., col2 = ...
```

Your update statement is missing the table reference.  It's not enough have a list of 3-part column names (and that's not good practice anyway.)

FWIW, you might be able to do this simpler using [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql), I think.  Worth checking out.

Comment: yes correct i have taken it from Merge and i am doing it using cursor as the sql version that i am using doesnot support MERGE. So, any other way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please review if my procedure is right or wrong now.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE IATFUPLOAD 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    --@p1 int = 0, 
    --@p2 int = 0

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @audit_id int, @audittype_id int, @CausingClause_id int
    declare @findings varchar(500), @Rating varchar(500), @lr_ind varchar(500), @root_cause varchar(500), @corr_action varchar(500), @by_whom varchar(500), @remarks varchar(500), @links varchar(500)
    declare @close_date datetime
    declare @count int
    set @count = 0
    declare @category_id_insert int

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    --SELECT @p1, @p2
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
                            SELECT  
                            AU.id                       AS audit_id,
                            AT.id                       AS audittype_id,
                            CC.id                       AS CausingClause_id,
                            IA.[Finding]                AS findings,
                            IA.[Rating]                 AS Rating,
                            IA.[Reach]          AS lr_ind,
                            IA.[Root_Cause]             AS root_cause,
                            IA.[Corrective_Action]      AS corr_action,
                            IA.[Action_Owner]           AS by_whom,
                            IA.[Remark_Verification]    AS remarks,
                            IA.[Links]                  AS links,
                            IA.[Close_Date]             AS close_date
                    FROM    [dbo].[IMPORT_AUDIT_REPORTS_EXCEL] AS IA,
                            [dbo].[CausingClause] AS CC,
                            [dbo].[Audit_Type] AS AT,                       
                            [dbo].[Audits] AS AU
                    WHERE   IA.ID           = CC.name
                    AND     IA.Audit_Type   = AT.name
                    AND     IA.Audit_No     = AU.id;

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @audit_id, @audittype_id,
@CausingClause_id,
@findings,
@Rating,
@lr_ind,
@root_cause,
@corr_action,
@by_whom,
@remarks,
@links, 
@close_date

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    SET @category_id_insert=(SELECT id FROM [dbo].CATEGORIES AS CA WHERE CA.name = @Rating)

   SET @COUNT = (select count(1)  from [dbo].[AUDIT_REPORTS] as Src where 
                    Src.ID= @audit_id
            AND     Src.audittype_id        = @audittype_id
            AND     Src.CausingClause_id    = @CausingClause_id)
    --PRINT @COUNT;

    if @COUNT>0
    UPDATE dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS SET    dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[audit_id]           = @audit_id,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[category_id]        = (SELECT id FROM [dbo].CATEGORIES AS CA WHERE CA.name = @Rating),
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[ref_id]         = 0,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[ref_ident]          = 'N/A',
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[findings]           = @findings,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[corr_action]        = @corr_action,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[lr_ind]         = @lr_ind,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[by_whom]            = @by_whom,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[remarks]            = @remarks,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[due_date]           = NULL,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[close_date]     = @close_date,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[audittype_id]       = @audittype_id,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[root_cause]     = @root_cause,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[links]              = @links,
                dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS .[CausingClause_id]   =@CausingClause_id
    Else

INSERT into dbo.AUDIT_REPORTS
    (
        [audit_id],
        [category_id],
        [ref_id],
        [ref_ident],
        [findings],
        [corr_action],
        [lr_ind],
        [by_whom],
        [remarks],
        [due_date],
        [close_date],
        [audittype_id],
        [root_cause],
        [links],
        [CausingClause_id]
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @audit_id,
        --0,
        @category_id_insert,
        0,
        'N/A',
        @findings,
        @corr_action,
        @lr_ind,
        @by_whom,
        @remarks,
        NULL,
        @close_date,
        @audittype_id,
        @root_cause,
        @links,
        @CausingClause_id
    );  
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor                    


END
GO
```